# Cypress BDD html report with screenshot for failed step

Tags: crystal-reports, cypress, bdd, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I want to attach the screenshot of failed step in html report for my BDD tests in cypress.

I am using "multiple-cucumber-html-reporter" and I am able to generate a BDD report of all test cases.

Below is my .js file that generates the html report:

```
const report = require("multiple-cucumber-html-reporter");
report.generate({
jsonDir: "cypress/reports",  // ** Path of .json file **//
reportPath: "./cypress/reports/cucumber-htmlreport.html",
metadata: {
browser: {
name: "chrome",
version: "81",
},
device: "Local test machine",
platform: {
name: "mac",
version: "Catalina",
},
},
});
```

I understand that in cypress's plugin for BDD html report we cannot work with scenario object as we used to do in cucumber.

How do I add code for taking screenshots here ?

Comment: I found a link to achieve what i need but I am not sure of the fix is for the pkugin OR something to tweak my project repository. https://github.com/jcundill/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/fixJson.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypress itself takes the screenshot of failed scenarios automatically. There should be no problem with taking the screenshots. see: [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/screenshots-and-videos.html#Screenshots) But if you mean to attach the SS into html report, I suggest you to switch to Allure reporting tool for Cypress. see the detailed info and report here: [allure reports](http://allure.qatools.ru/)

Comment: I just want to underline that you need to install openJDK for Allure to run.

Comment: Thanks @Celoaga. Allure reports worked for me. I just downloaded 2 plugins viz. "Allure-commandLine" and "cypress-allure-plugin".

Comment: if I add the allure=true in cypress.json's env parameter. Do I still need to pass the env variable in commandline ?